# How to start the text mode installer from the Kubuntu 12.04 DVD?

Tags: boot, system-installation, kubuntu, debian-installer, text-mode

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 12.04 from the DVD, and I want the text-mode installer. I don't see how I can get to it from the boot menu. What should I enter as the boot options? Or should I start the installer from the command-line after boot?

**Notes:**

- In the F4 modes menu, I only see the 'normal mode'.
- I know I can achieve this with the alternate boot CD. But I want this on the DVD, with all the packages the DVD has (e.g. for installations with no Internet access).

Comment: Does the option show up if you press F4?

Comment: @soulsource: No, it does not

Comment: You probably need the alternate. See: http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download-lts

Comment: @Rinzwind: For various reasons I won't go into, I want to use the DVD, not the alternate. Is a text-mode installation impossible from the Kubuntu DVD? That seems unlikely.

Comment: @einpoklum how much did the image weighs?

Answer (score 2):

For text based install you need to get the Alternate CD.

The text based alternate installer can be downloaded from the various download methods above. This installation CD is suited for computers unable to run the graphical desktop based installation, either because their computer does not meet the minimum requirements for the live CD or because their computer requires configuration after the installation is complete in order to use the desktop. The alternate installer also includes advanced features such as LVM support.

Desktop Alternate [32bit CD](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/precise/release/kubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-i386.iso.torrent), and Desktop Alternate [64bit CD](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/precise/release/kubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent).

**Added info**

Thanks to [soulsource](https://askubuntu.com/users/17056/soulsource), the Kubuntu website does state that **"The DVD includes both the live image/desktop installer and text based alternate installer"**.  So how to start the text based installer from the DVD?  Well I had to download the DVD version of Kubuntu, and once booted from the DVD, I was presented with a menu, one of the options was to Install Kubuntu in text mode.  See image below.

**Note**: The Kubuntu CD is 704MB, where as the DVD is 3.7GB.  Make sure that you downloaded the right file.  The CD version will not have the text install, for that you need to get the Alternate CD.  Where as the DVD version will have the live image/desktop installer and text based alternate installer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Kubuntu Website says that the DVD also includes the text based installer.

Comment: "Do not be confused, even though DVDs can hold far more data than the typical Kubuntu CD, the main benefit of the DVD downloads is to get access to all of the available language packs during install. Most people will be fine with the standard CD installer. The DVD includes both the live image/desktop installer and text based alternate installer."

Comment: I'm not confused. I know that that's why I referenced you in the answer, since you're the one that stated that. The DVD even holds some extra software, and codecs.

Comment: I did not download any Kubuntu installation medium. The text above is a quote from http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download-lts - that's why I put quotation marks.

Comment: I never said I used the DVD at any time. All I did was to point out that the Kubuntu Website says that the DVD also includes the text based installer and then I copy pasted the relevant part of text from the website. For *all* my *buntu installations I used the Alternate CD.

Comment: I did not see this entry in the menu. Can you add a screenshot of the boot options you get when selecting this?

Comment: @einpoklum are you sure you did not download the CD version and burned it on to a DVD? The CD does -not- have the text based installation option. The DVD does. Please answer the comment below the question posed by Braiam.